# In a Windows Forms program what event can I capture to paint on a picturebox in a tab control?

Tags: windows, forms, picturebox, tabcontrol

I have a Windows Form program that contains a tab control. The tab in question contains a user control, which in turn contains a picturebox. When I select the tab at run time I can't figure out which event will let me draw in the picture box. I have tried all of the events that I can find, and I can single step through them and see it drawing what I want, but when I click 'Continue' from the debugger to run the picture box clears.

I have ended up putting in a 'refresh' button to draw what I want after its done loading, but I'm certain I'm missing something.

What am I missing?

Comment: PictureBox is derived from the Control class, so you'll want to use the [Paint Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx) to do your drawing.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that. If I single step through it will draw but when I click 'continue' it clears the picture box. Its as if there is another event taking place.

Comment: Can you post the code in your paint event?

Comment: `g.Clear(Color.White);`
`g.DrawArc(Pens.Blue, 50,50, 14, 14, 0, 360);`

Comment: This can't be all your code. What is `g`?

Comment: I've stripped it for debugging. g is a Graphics object declared in the user control which contains the picturebox. It is initialized when the usercontrol is created. I can single step into the paint routine and see the drawing, but when I go it redraws.

Comment: This is wrong. You should be using the graphics object that's passed into the event. Don't create your own. Instead use `e.Graphics.Clear` and `e.Graphics.DrawArc`.

Comment: That was it! When I used the Graphics object from the event handler the drawing persisted.  If you'd like to post that as the answer I'll note it so you get the points. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the graphics object passed into the event handler. Like this:

```
public void UserControl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{  
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
    e.Graphics.DrawArc(Pens.Blue, 50, 50, 14, 14, 0, 360);
}
```

Also, you might be tempted to dispose of the graphics object. Don't do this. Never dispose of an object that you didn't create.